# PageViewer not showing view via class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

For my app I have a base main activity, which holds a pageviewer.
In the activity class I have:

```
MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The adapter class looks like:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<LinearLayout> views;

public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    views = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
    views.add(new questionListView(context));
}

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View view, int arg1, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) view).removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return views.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View view, int position) {
        View myView = views.get(position);
        ((ViewPager) view).addView(myView);
        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0) {

    }

    }
    }
}
```

The questionListView class looks like:

```
public class questionListView extends LinearLayout {

public questionListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public questionListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {

    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View myView = factory.inflate(R.layout.view1,null);

    addView(myView);

}

}
```

Main activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!--
    This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page
    titles for adjacent pages.
    -->

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:alpha="4"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

view1 is a layout view, a linearlayout with other layouts in them.

When I run the app the main activity is shown, but the view with the view1-layout is not.

Why not, what am I doing wrong here?
I'm not getting any errors.

rg,
Eric

Comment: No one with an idea to help me?

Comment: Is that the full code of your `PagerAdapter`?

Comment: it is now, I updated it.

Comment: The adapter looks ok(although I don't understand why did you implement those (empty) methods if you're not going to do something in them). I would say that the problem is with the `ViewPager` itself and how you use it in the layout(?!). Can you show the layout where you use the `ViewPager` or other details about it?

Comment: added the acivity layout.
The empty methods are empty because I haven't done anything with it yet. My first goal was to actually see something. ;-)

Comment: Set the height of the `PagerTitleStrip` to `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luksprog help solved the problem.
Setting the PagerTitleStrip to wrap_content solved it.